# Strengthening the conclusion of the nested intervals theorem

Tags: real-analysis

The nested interval theorem says that the intersection of any decreasing sequence of nonempty closed bounded intervals is nonempty. Is the following strengthening of the conclusion valid: The intersection is either a singleton or a closed bounded interval $[x,y]$?

Comment: According to Wikipedia's definition of nested intervals the intersection is always a singleton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals#Theorem

Comment: @blamocur True, but I am not assuming the hypothesis that the length of the intervals is going to 0.

Comment: The I believe your conclusion is valid. BTW, a singleton is just a special case of a closed bounded interval.

Comment: Yes this is correct.